# Finding a real-valued function not differentiable in any $B_{r}(\mathbf{x})$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a function $f:O\to \mathbb{R}$, $O$ is an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which satisfies  both $(1)$ and $(2)$ ?

$(1)$ All of its second partial derivatives are defined on $O$ and continuous at $(x_0,y_0)\in O$ ;

$(2)$ It is not differentiable in any neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0).$

---

Obviously, $(1)$ involves the differentiability of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$.

The original post come from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546065/is-f-p-times-differentiable-at-x0). In order to express my purpose clearly, I simplify $n$-variables to two-variables.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Indeed, if your condition (1) holds, then 
all of the second-order partial derivatives of $f$ are bounded on an open neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)$. So, by Lemma 1 below, both of the first-order partial derivatives of $f$ are Lipschitz and hence continuous on $U$, and therefore your condition (2) cannot hold.

> **Lemma 1.** If $|g''_{xx}|+|g''_{yy}|+|g''_{xy}|+|g''_{yx}|\le M$ on $U$, then 
>   $|f'_x(x,y)-f'_x(a,b)|\le M|x-a|+M|y-b|$ and $|f'_y(x,y)-f'_y(a,b)|\le M|x-a|+M|y-b|$ for all $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ in $U$.

*Proof.* For any $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ in $U$,
$$|f'_x(x,y)-f'_x(a,b)|\le|f'_x(x,y)-f'_x(a,y)|+|f'_x(a,y)-f'_x(a,b)| \\
\le M|x-a|+M|y-b|.$$
Similarly, 
$$|f'_y(x,y)-f'_y(a,b)|\le M|x-a|+M|y-b|.\quad\Box$$